# Prevent Finder to launch on boot

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

I do not need Finder because I use Ranger in CLI and I manually quit it (I added the quit option) each time I boot (mainly not to have it in the way when I use to switch applications with cmd + tab).

If it's not possible, an alternative would be to quit it from the terminal and I would do a script that is launched on boot. But after "killall Finder", Finder relaunch automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just disable the LaunchAgent com.apple.finder at /System/Library/LaunchAgents/

with `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist` and Finder shouldn't launch at all.

Depending on your system this might not be successful. Then download, install and open [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/). Navigate to System Agents -> com.apple.Finder and highlight it. In the menubar choose Job -> Unload. Then hit the radio button next to com.apple.Finder and disable it.

Comment: This the response I get : `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist: Could not find specified service`

Comment: It works like a charm with LaunchControl !

Answer (score 0):

You can change the automatically launched program via this command:

```
defaults write com.apple.loginwindow Finder /PATH/TO/ALTERNATIVE.app
```

The alternative program will launch instead of Finder; and the force-quit option will change to "restart", etc.

The actual Finder can still be started, but it can also be quit, just as any other normal app.